# Powershell How to get character count at word document?

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I need to get count of character in word document via power shell ?
it is any way to do it ? I have some code like this but I suggest it is could be way without Paragraphs

```
     $Word = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
    $Word.Visible = $False
    $datasheet = $word.Documents.Open("d:\Test words.docx")
    
    
    $FirstParagraph = $datasheet.Paragraphs[1].range.Text
    $FirstParagraph | measure -Line -Character -Word

$datasheet.close()
$word.Quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
$Word = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $False
$datasheet = $word.Documents.Open("c:\temp\test.docx")
$Word.ActiveDocument.Content.Select()

$NbCharacter=$Word.ActiveDocument.Characters.Count.ToString()

"File has $NbCharacter charactere"

$datasheet.close()
$word.Quit()
```

Comment: thanks working well, but I have small question word directly shows 48 character for example, but script 56. I understand it is some hidden character, it is anyway to get value what word shows in UI ?

Comment: your script have endilne and tabulation character i think

Comment: do you mean document ? how to skip them ?

Comment: vba counts things that the Word Interface does not. When checking for "words" I found a ratio of about 1.13:1. If you check the ratio for characters, you can get a very good approximation through vba by reducing the result to reflect that ratio.