# Powershell - counting characters in Word documents - including headers and footers

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I need to count the number of characters in a word document *including* the characters in the headers and footers. I can successfully count the number of chars in the main document, thanks to the help I got here :
[Powershell How to get character count at word document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080479/powershell-how-to-get-character-count-at-word-document)
but I have not succeeded in finding how to get to the headers and footers.
Any ideas ?
Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

EDIT :

following code loops through the headers and footers of a word document but I can not seem to be able to get their sizes.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$browser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$null = $browser.ShowDialog()
$path = $browser.SelectedPath

Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -File | 
Foreach-Object {
$Word = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
$filename = $_.FullName
$Word.Visible = $False
$datasheet = $word.Documents.Open($filename,$false, $true)

$Word.ActiveDocument.Content.Select()
 

foreach ($section in $datasheet.Sections)
{
    ForEach ($header in $section.Headers)
    {
        #$header.Range.Fields.Update() | Out-Null
        $NbHeader = $header.Range.Text.Count.ToString()
        "header $NbHeader"
    }
    ForEach ($footer in $section.Footers)
    {
        #$footer.Range.Fields.Update() | Out-Null
        $NbFooter = $footer.Range.Text.Count.ToString()
        "footer $NbFooter"
    }
}


$datasheet.close()
$word.Quit()
}
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Comment: Additionally you may ask directly through a comment under the answer that you linked to. It is likely that the answerer has an answer for your current question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access both the Headers and the Footers from the Document.Sections property.  There are different headers/footers for primary, first page, and even pages so we loop through each with `ForEach-Object` (shown below with alias '%'), trim any whitespace off the end and filter out any that are only whitespace.

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject 'Word.Application'
$doc = $word.Documents.Open('C:\temp\word_count.docx', $null, $true)

& {
    $doc.Paragraphs | % Range | % Text | % TrimEnd

    $doc.Sections | % Headers | % Range | % Paragraphs | % Range | % Text | % TrimEnd | ? {-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)} 

    $doc.Sections | % Footers | % Range | % Paragraphs | % Range | % Text | % TrimEnd | ? {-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)} 

} | Measure-Object length -Sum | ForEach-Object Sum

$doc.Close()
$word.Quit()
```

---

To test and show what is being counted try this

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject 'Word.Application'
$doc = $word.Documents.Open('C:\temp\wordcount.docx', $null, $true)

& {
    $doc.Paragraphs | % Range | % Text | % TrimEnd

    $doc.Sections | % Headers | % Range | % Paragraphs | % Range | % Text | % TrimEnd | Where-Object { -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) } 

    $doc.Sections | % Footers | % Range | % Paragraphs | % Range | % Text | % TrimEnd | Where-Object { -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) } 

} | ForEach-Object -Begin {$tally = 0} {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Length = $_.length
        Tally = $tally += $_.length
        Text = $_
    } 
} 

$doc.Close()
$word.Quit()
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ! I understand now what I have to do :-) using your example however I seem to get the same amount of chars as when counting just the main text ... Anyway I will play a bit further with it !

Comment: I seem to be unable to extract the number of chars of headers and footers... is it possible to do something like $sizeofobject | Measure-Object -property length -character ? or something similar to $NbCharacter=$Word.ActiveDocument.Characters.Count.ToString() but for headers and footers ?

Comment: You're right.  The code wasn't working as expected.  Not sure why.  Sorry about that.  This updated code seems to be working as far as I can tell.  Let me know

Comment: no problem, I appreciate the help ! :-) I'm not used to this powershell syntax so I am not sure if I am doing it right but I still don't get near the char count I can see for the document within Word itself. I have tried to loop through the headers and footers (see my code above) but I fail to counts the chars properly ...

Comment: I confirmed it, your code also only counts the chars of the main document, it does not access the chars in the headers and the footers ... I will work around this by assuming that the size of the footers is an percentage of the size of the main document. It's not ideal but I have no other idea so far :-)

Comment: @OlivierS I don't know how you confirmed it, but the script above does include header and footers.  You can remove the `| Measure-Object length -Sum | ForEach-Object Sum` part and see what is outputted to be measured.  When I test this code the headers and footers are definitely included.

Comment: @OlivierS, try the new code I just added to show what is being counted

Comment: I am sorry to say that it was 100% my mistake, I added the extra text to count into the footnotes instead of the footers, your code works and I thank you very much for all your help ! :-)